# erro ao aplicar template no dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end, dropzonejs

Estou com dificuldades em entender o funcionamento da alteração do template do [dropzoneJS](https://www.dropzonejs.com/)
Mesmo consultando a documentação não compreendi como é feita essa alteração.
Resultado final que eu gostaria de de obter é [imagem1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmtd4.png)

Meus stylesheets estão ok.
ao aplicar o dropzone ele me retorna o

**ERRO**
 [imagem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iCq0.png)

```
 `dropzone.min.js:766 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at Dropzone.addedfile (dropzone.min.js:766)
    at Dropzone.emit (dropzone.min.js:89)
    at Dropzone.addFile (dropzone.min.js:1905)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (dropzone.min.js:1266)`
```

**HTML**

```
`<div class="row m-b-sm m-t-sm">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" id="chose-files-btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm dz-clickable"> SELECIONAR ARQUIVOS</button>
        <button type="button" id="delete-all-files-btn" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm"> REMOVER TUDO</button>
        <button type="button" id="send-all-files-btn" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"> ENVIAR TUDO</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="project-list" id="dropzoneCustom">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
        <tr id="tpl">
            <td class="project-status">
                <span class="label label-primary" data-dz-size></span>
            </td>
            <td class="project-status">
                <span class="label label-danger text-uppercase" data-dz-errormessage></span>
            </td>
            <td class="project-title">
                <span data-dz-name></span>
                <br/>
                <small data-dz-size></small>
            </td>
            <td class="project-completion">
                <small>Completion with: 28%</small>
                <div class="progress progress-mini">
                    <div data-dz-uploadprogress class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="project-people">
                <img data-dz-thumbnail />
            </td>
            <td class="project-actions">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>`
```

**JAVA SCRIPT / JQUERY**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $('#dropzoneCustom').dropzone({
        previewsContainer: "#tpl",
        clickable: "#chose-files-btn",
        url: "{{route('photos.store')}}",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        method: "POST",
        parallelUploads: 5,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        paramName: "profilePhotos",
        maxFiles: 50,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        previewTemplate: $('#tpl').innerHTML,
    });
```

Comment: Você está usando algum framework de front-end?

Comment: Estou usando o Bootstrap 4 e Jquery 3.5 somente

Answer (score 0):

Na linha 766 do dropzone.min.js alguma variável está como "undefined", nessa pergunta tiveram uma dúvida parecida, vê se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733423/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-trim-of-undefined-in-jquery

Comment: Ainda não consegui.

Comment: Essa lina refere-se ao codifo fonte do DropzoneJS